# How to update Firebase Database from a PHP script on Heroku?

Tags: php, firebase, heroku

I am working on updating my firebase database using PHP. I have the following code working fine on my local server. But when I push my project to Heroku servers I get an HTTP 500 error.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type:application/json");
if (!isset($_GET["token"]))
{
echo "Technical error";
exit();
}
if ($_GET["token"]!='1234567890')
{
echo "Invalid authorization";
exit();
}
if (!$request=file_get_contents('php://input'))
{
echo "Invalid input";
exit();
}





require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;


$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/kshdkhalsdhf77^&5/adfy-9ee95-815198ad0dcc.json');

$firebase = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    ->create();

$database = $firebase->getDatabase();

$newPost = $database
    ->getReference('Users/user1')
    ->push([
        'Amount' => 200,
        'Phone Number' => 000000
    ]);





 echo '{"ResultCode":0,"ResultDesc":"Confirmation received successfully"}';

?>
```

I was trouble shooting the code and found out that the problem starts just right at the require statement. If I comment out the code that gets the Firebase database everything works and the HTTP 500 error goes away.

How can I solve this?

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. In this case, try running `heroku logs` and seeing what's in there.

Comment: I'd guess that your dependencies haven't been properly installed (but of course we can't know for sure until you [edit] your question and include some details from your logs). Are your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files included in your Git repository?

Comment: composer.lock and composer.json are all included

Comment: What about my first question, David? What do your logs say? The 500 error on its own is almost useless for troubleshooting.